# RegEx with ISO Currency and String Match

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

`^USD|AUD|BRL|GBP|CAD|CNY|DKK|AED|EUR|HKD|INR|MYR|MXN|NZD|PHP|SGD|THB|ARS|COP|CLP|PEN|VEF$`

When using this example string: `16ccf52b144~~refCode-3-d5779a89-d437-448a-bf53-efad2cdd66f6~20191020T16:00~20191026T16:00~USD~305.81~~~~**8294A2B49CD60ABE4FC7081F05CD06AA17E837CCADEB0ABC57B6AC94B09882FB`

I am expecting the regex to return USD, instead it is returning CAD. How can I edit the regex so that it returns USD ...Ideally regex should look at `~currencyCode~` ...instead right now it is looking at `currencyCode` without tilde.

Comment: Why do you have the anchors in your pattern? (`^` and `$`) ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure - Is this not needed? I need to look for pattern ~currencyCode~

Answer (score 2):

The `^` and `$` assertions are unnecessary in your regex since the substring you are trying to match is at neither the beginning nor the end of the string, and the fact that `^` is preceding `USD` means that the pattern can only match `USD` if it is at the beginning of the string.

Instead, group the alternations and surround them with word boundary assertions:

```
\b(?:USD|AUD|BRL|GBP|CAD|CNY|DKK|AED|EUR|HKD|INR|MYR|MXN|NZD|PHP|SGD|THB|ARS|COP|CLP|PEN|VEF)\b
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the other answer? How come you didn't add check for ~ here? Thanks!

Comment: The difference comes down to different assumptions in where the substring you're looking for is located within the input string. Since you did not clearly state the exact format the input string has to be bound to, we are simply making different assumptions by observing the input. I'm assuming that the currency substring is preceded and superceded by a non-word, while @JDB is assuming that it is preceded and superceded by a `~`. I chose to use `\b` because it is supported by more regex engines. The lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` used in @JDB's answer is not supported by JavaScript, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which language or framework you're using, so I'll assume you want a generally applicable regex.

If you know that `~` will precede and follow your currency, then you can use a [zero-width assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find text between `~` characters like so:

```
(?<=~)(USD|AUD|BRL|GBP|CAD|CNY|DKK|AED|EUR|HKD|INR|MYR|MXN|NZD|PHP|SGD|THB|ARS|COP|CLP|PEN|VEF)(?=~)
```

This will match the `USD` in `6:00~USD~305` because it's surrounded by `~`, but not the `CAD` in `7CCADEB0` because it's not surrounded by them.

Comment: I am using JavaScript. What does the (?<=~) do? Can I just use (~)?

Comment: @Michael `(?<=)` is called a lookbehind. `(?=)` is called a lookahead. You can check out the link for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Can you or someone explain what the difference in regex from this answer to the answer below using group capturing?

Comment: Zero-width assertions are a big topic that don't fit neatly into an SO post. I recommend you read the article I linked to for more information.